# Define datablock in C with "pointers"

Tags: c++, c, c-preprocessor

For supporting a legacy menu structure in an embedded device (based on a STM32 processor) were looking for a way to define a datablock. The definition is fixed and cannot be changed. It's important the block has no gaps and the data lays in memory the way it is defined.

The structure look something like this in bytes

[Option][VariableByte1][VariableByte2][VariableByte3][VariableByte4][MetaDataOffsetByte1][MetaDataOffsetByte1]...(number of definitions)....[MetadataFormat][MinValue][MaxValue]...(number of definitions)....

In pseudo C the first part could be implemented as

```
#define OPTIONA 0x33
#define VAR(name) (&Name & 0xFF), ((&Name >> 8) & 0xFF)

#define METAFORMAT1 0x2
#define MAKEINT(value) (value & 0xFF), ((value >> 8) & 0xFF)
#define OFFSET /*Some preprocessor magic*/
char data[] =
{
 OPTION, VAR(someVariable), OFFSET(meta1)
 OPTION, VAR(someVariable), OFFSET(meta1),
 OPTION, VAR(someVariable), OFFSET(meta2),
meta1:
 METAFORMAT1, MAKEINT(0), MAKEINT(99),
meta2:
 METAFORMAT2, MAKEINT(-99), MAKEINT(0),
}
```

Now were looking for the "Some preprocessor magic" implementation.

As an alternative we've looked into defining the and meta part as structs or unions but when doing this, there not much guaranty the values will be put into memory in this order. For bonus points it would be nice if the solution is portable over some compilers, and the definition is done compile time.

Some environment facts:

- We use the keil-arm-mdk compiler
- It compiles C code with the standard C++ settings
- We only want to define a byte pattern in memory (the application does not interact with this structure

Comment: [tag:C] or [tag:C++]? Also, which compiler?

Comment: The code is C code compiled with a C/C++ compiler. Preferably a generic solution but we use the keil-mdk-arm compiler.

Comment: Again, C or C++?  They are not the same.  In general, a "C/C++ compiler" is *probably* better described simply as a C++ compiler, but perhaps it has an option to compile in C mode, and if so, it matters whether you are using that option.

Comment: And again, which compiler, specifically?  Also, are you trying to define a bit pattern for general objects in memory, or are you trying to map ROM or hardware I/O registers?  That might not matter as much, I guess, but your requirements are a little unclear.

Comment: It's an ISO C++ compiler, that does not support wide streams and export templates, either with or without the ARM extensions. We're using it to compile C constructs (so no classes, exceptions etc).  The compiler is the "keil-mdk-arm" compiler as mentioned earlier.  We are trying to define a bit/byte pattern in memory.

Comment: What's up with `MAKEINT()`?  Each use results in code applying the address-of operator (unary `&`) to a constant.  Also, it looks like it may use the logical 'and' operator (`&&`) where you mean to use the bitwise 'and' operator (binary `&`).  Similarly for `VAR()`: do you mean to store bytes of the argument's *value* or of its *address*?  And there, too, do you really mean to use `&&`, as opposed to `&`?

Comment: Your remarks about the macros are correct. I've corrected it.

Comment: What does it mean to define a pattern in memory? Why do you need it if you don't interact with that memory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bottom line: you cannot have what you asked for in exactly the form you asked for.  The preprocessor can do all sorts of amusing tricks, but it works left-to-right, top-to-bottom, so there is no way to make it look ahead to determine a relative offset to something it has yet to process.

You should consider writing a function to perform this initialization.  That would be by far the best alternative unless you need to initialize global datablocks at the point where they are declared (as opposed to, for example, at the beginning of `main()`).

Alternatively, if for some reason  you do need to do this at global scope, a lot, then you should consider writing a code generator to produce the datablock initializers, instead of doing it directly in C.

If you don't want to do either of the above, then you could consider something along these lines:

```
#define BYTE(i) ((i) & 0xff)
#define LE2(i)  BYTE(i), BYTE((i) >> 8)
#define LE4(i)  BYTE(i), BYTE((i) >> 8), BYTE((i) >> 16), BYTE((i) >> 24)

/* The number of bytes in a variable entry */
#define VAR_SIZE    7
/*
 * The bytes of a variable entry.  The entries for one data block must appear
 * one per line on consecutive lines, without any intervening lines, by the
 * metadata.
 * - option is the option code
 * - var is the value to be stored in the entry (as a variable or a literal)
 * - meta is the 1-based index of the metadata format entry for this variable
 * - start is the source line number of the first variable entry
 * - nvars is the total number of variable entries in the data block
 */
#define VARIABLE(option, var, meta, start, nvars) BYTE(option), LE4(var), \
    LE2((((start) + (nvars)) - __LINE__) * VAR_SIZE + ((meta) - 1) * MD_SIZE)

/* The number of bytes in a metadata format entry */
#define MD_SIZE     5
/*
 * The bytes of a metadata format entry.  The metadata format entries for one
 * data block must appear one per line on consecutive lines, starting on the
 * line after that of the last variable entry for the block.
 * - format is the format code
 * - min is the minimum value
 * - max is the maximum value
 */
#define METADATA(format, min, max) BYTE(code), LE2(min), LE2(max)

#define OPTIONA     0x32
#define OPTIONB     0x33
#define METAFORMAT1 0x2
#define METAFORMAT2 0x7

#define THIS_BLOCK_NVARS 3
/*
 * Hack alert!
 * The source layout of the following declarations is critical.  Do not merge
 * lines or introduce additional lines without understanding what you are doing!
 */
static int decl_start = __LINE__ + 2;
unsigned char data[] = {
    VARIABLE(OPTIONA, varName1, 1, decl_start, THIS_BLOCK_NVARS),
    VARIABLE(OPTIONA, varName2, 1, decl_start, THIS_BLOCK_NVARS),
    VARIABLE(OPTIONB, varName3, 2, decl_start, THIS_BLOCK_NVARS),
    METADATA(METAFORMAT1, 0, 99),
    METADATA(METAFORMAT2, -99, 0)
};
```

(That may need to be adjusted a bit depending on the precise definition of the offsets you need.)  All the macro definitions there except `THIS_BLOCK_NVARS` are reusable for any number of data block declarations.  That gives you a relatively simple form.  It is a bit brittle, though, in that it relies on the preprocessor's `__LINE__` macro to determine the index of each variable entry, and therefore it is sensitive to addition and removal of lines (which is in part the point).

Also **very important**: the code is valid C++, but it is *not* valid C99 on account of the initializer's use of data that is not a compile-time constant (`varname1`, etc.).  Since you are in fact compiling with a C++ compiler, you can probably accommodate that.